# Access mobile telephone number / Network data via jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to access a user's mobile phone number/network name via jQuery to auto-fill a form on a mobile website? I've searched around and can't find anything cross phone/browser

Comment: Normally JS running in the browser can't access details about the system the browser is running on. (And I _really_ hope this applies in the case of personal details like phone numbers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to access that data from the browser. The only way to access data like that on a mobile device is to have a native app. If you really need that functionality, I would look into Phonegap or appmobi. They allow you to build native apps using HTML5/Javascript.